# How to Read and Edit IPTC "Writer/Editor" tag using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, iptc

I am creating a WPF application that can read and write IPTC and XMP image metadata. I am having problem reading and writing the IPTC Writer/Editor property. The XMP counterpart of it works fine. I have tried the following options but no luck.

metaData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/Writer/Editor", value)

metaData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/Writer-Editor", value)

metaData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/Writer Editor", value)

metaData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/Caption/Description Writer", value)

Would greatly appreciate any pointers/help to access the Writer/Editor tag.

muruge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from the following [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/591c6700-efcc-4e10-bfc0-b48b6d2d757c).

It had to metaData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/Writer\/Editor", value)

Anyways Thanks to all..